# Eclipse plugins for Spring / Hibernate development?

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, orm, jakarta-ee, eclipse-plugin

I have a running dynamic web project in Eclipse (Java EE + Maven + Spring). I am at the point where I need to integrate a persistence layer and want to use Hibernate with a MySql database.

I am wondering what plugins would be useful for me at this point?  For Hibernate should I install `hibernate tools` or is it not necessary?  Are then any plugins that are most widely use for connecting / exploring database connections that would be appropriate for the type of project I am working on?  Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Hibernate Tools](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/tools.html) is definitely a nice plugin (that provides wizards, a nice console useful to setup the HQL queries, a mapping editor, etc). I'm actually tempted to say: why not using it? I use it in conjunction with the database support provided by the Eclipse [Data Tools Platform](http://www.eclipse.org/datatools/downloads.php) (that is included in the [Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/galileo/SR1/eclipse-jee-galileo-SR1-linux-gtk.tar.gz) or available via the update manager). In your case, I would maybe just consider using [SpringSource Tools Suite](http://www.springsource.com/products/sts) as base instead of a vanilla Eclipse.

**Update:** As reminded by BalusC in a comment, the Hibernate Tools also include a database reverse engineering tool which is maybe the most powerful feature. I should have mentioned it, this is now fixed.

Comment: +1 Hibernate Tools is definitely great. I would only mention the useful reverse engineering part as well.

Comment: @BalusC Very true, maybe the most powerful feature indeed. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

You can look at http://fast-code.sourceforge.net/ as well. You can create FooService and FooServiceImpl and the configurations just by typing foo. It has nice way to create unit tests as well.